# is "buying the dip" ever profitable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have been thinking about this problem for a little while and I think it is a multivariable calculus problem. I am currently studying calculus and I would like to see how someone would solve this.

> Say you invested \$100 in the stock market. If the market goes up 20% you profit $20. Due to volatility, your investment would be up some days and down others. What if you invested a portion of your money and saved a portion to buy on the days the market goes down and sell once the market has recouped - "buying the dip."

For the sake of argument, we can assume that the invested funds will appreciate $x$ percent in any given time period ($t$) and that the value of those funds will depreciate at least by $y$ percent $n$ times a year.

trying to work out this problem is driving me down an ever more complex rabbit hole. The way I am going about this is to assume that the "dips" are evenly spaced within the time period and are uniformly 10% declines.

> \$100 -> \$110
>
> \$99 -> \$108
>
> $10 x 11.111% = 0.11111
>
> 99 + 9 + 0.11111 + 10 = 118.11111

(principle) + (profit) + (profit from dip) + (reserve for buying dips)

If you made a 11.111% profit from each dip then it would take a little over 18 profitable dips to make up for the $2 of lost profit from having a portion of funds in cash.

How do I translate this into a calculus problem?

Comment: It's not a simple matter.  If you assume that moves are random (with some fixed drift, say) then there is no point at all to this strategy.  By definition, in this case, every possible move has expectation $0$ (risk adjusted).  People who believe in the strategy believe in a more subtle process, one with mean reversion say.  There isn't a one-size-fits-all mathematical answer to the question.

Comment: The market doesn't work like you say it does. The assumptions are wrong.  This requires fairly advanced calculus in the form probability theory. Perhaps look at random walks and stochastic diff eq.

Comment: To have a well-defined problem, you need to specify a probability model for the market's behaviour, and to define an objective.  Beware of cases where the expected return keeps increasing but with probability $1$ your fortune goes to $0$ (e.g. [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=127116)).

Comment: Don't get hung up on the probability, I am more interested in the calculus problem. I don't think any "strategy" really works, only exploitation of market inefficiencies or just straight up rigging the game (HFT). I am just curious how this would translate into a calculus problem.